# Multiple Filter using jquery with data attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to use multiple filters using `data` attributes. It's working in combination but not working alone. Here is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="sts">
            <h1>filter 1</h1>
            </h1>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input data-id="1" class="st" type="checkbox" />
                    1
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input data-id="2" class="st" type="checkbox" />
                    2
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input data-id="3" class="st" type="checkbox" />
                    3
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>filter 2</h1>
        <div class="ats">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input data-id="foo" class="at" type="checkbox" />
                    foo
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input data-id="boo" class="at" type="checkbox" />
                    boo
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input data-id="bar" class="at" type="checkbox" />
                    bar
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1>filter 3</h1>
        <div class="dpts">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input data-id="a" class="dpt" type="checkbox" />
                    a
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input data-id="b" class="dpt" type="checkbox" />
                    b
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input data-id="c" class="dpt" type="checkbox" />
                    c
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input data-id="d" class="dpt" type="checkbox" />
                    d
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
    <li data-a="foo" data-st="1" data-dpt="a">asdw</li>
    <li data-a="boo" data-st="2" data-dpt="c">qwedf</li>
    <li data-a="boo" data-st="1" data-dpt="a">qwedf</li>
    <li data-a="bar" data-st="3" data-dpt="b">tazxsw</li>
    <li data-a="bar" data-st="1" data-dpt="b">zxcvb</li>
    <li data-a="foo" data-st="1" data-dpt="b">poiuy</li>
    <li data-a="boo" data-st="2" data-dpt="d">lkjhg</li>
    <li data-a="boo" data-st="3" data-dpt="d">lkjhg</li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.at, .dpt,.st').on('click', function() {
        var checkedat = $('.at:checked');
        var checkeddept = $('.dpt:checked');
        var checkedst = $('.st:checked');
        if (checkedat.length || checkeddept.length || checkedst.length) {
            if (checkeddept.length === 0) {
                $('.list > li').hide();
                $.each(checkedat, function() {
                    var prdId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    $.each(checkedst, function() {
                        var brandId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                        $('.list > li[data-a="' + prdId + '"][data-st="' + brandId + '"]').show();
                    });
                });
            } else if (checkedat.length === 0) {
                $('.list > li').hide();
                $.each(checkedst, function() {
                    var brandId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    $.each(checkeddept, function() {
                        var DeptId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                        $('.list > li[data-st="' + brandId + '"][data-dpt="' + DeptId + '"]').show();
                    });
                });
            } else if (checkedat.length === 0) {
                $('.list > li').hide();
                $.each(checkeddept, function() {
                    var DeptId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    $.each(checkedst, function() {
                        var brandId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                        $('.list > li[data-dpt="' + DeptId + '"][data-st="' + brandId + '"]').show();
                    });
                });
            } else {
                $('.list > li').hide();
                $.each(checkedat, function() {
                    var prdId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    $.each(checkedst, function() {
                        var brandId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                        $.each(checkeddept, function() {
                            var DeptId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                            $('.list > li[data-a="' + prdId + '"][data-dpt="' + DeptId + '"][data-st="' + brandId + '"]').show();
                        });
                    });
                });

            }
        } else {
            $('.list > li').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [**jsFiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/hguqrc3d/)

If i check any options from filter 1 & filter 2 & filter 3 its working , but when i click any option from filter 1 or filter 2 its not working

Comment: _"but a single filter is not working."_ Which portion of `javascript` are you referencing?

Comment: @guest271314 can you pls check the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is *a lot* more complicated than it needs to be. You should look in to using DRY principles as you can make this much more simple.

First, put a common class on all the checkboxes (I used `.stat` in my example). Then use a data attribute to denote the type of the stat. From there you can loop through each checked stat and hide/show the related `li` by using `filter()` to match them based on the `data-stat` and `data-id`. Something like this:

```js
$('.stat').on('click', function() {
  var $stats = $('.stat:checked');
  var $items = $('.list li');

  $items.show();
  if ($stats.length == 0)
    return;

  $stats.each(function() {
    var $stat = $(this);
    $items.filter(function() {
      return $(this).data($stat.data('type')) != $stat.data('id');
    }).hide();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="sts">
      <h1>filter 1</h1>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input data-id="1" data-type="st" class="stat st" type="checkbox" />1
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input data-id="2" data-type="st" class="stat st" type="checkbox" />2
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input data-id="3" data-type="st" class="stat st" type="checkbox" />3
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>filter 2</h1>
    <div class="ats">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input data-id="foo" data-type="at" class="stat at" type="checkbox" />foo
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input data-id="boo" data-type="at" class="stat at" type="checkbox" />boo
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input data-id="bar" data-type="at" class="stat at" type="checkbox" />bar
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h1>filter 3</h1>
    <div class="dpts">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input data-id="a" data-type="dpt" class="stat dpt" type="checkbox" />a
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input data-id="b" data-type="dpt" class="stat dpt" type="checkbox" />b
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input data-id="c" data-type="dpt" class="stat dpt" type="checkbox" />c
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input data-id="d" data-type="dpt" class="stat dpt" type="checkbox" />d
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li data-at="foo" data-st="1" data-dpt="a">asdw</li>
  <li data-at="boo" data-st="2" data-dpt="c">qwedf</li>
  <li data-at="boo" data-st="1" data-dpt="a">qwedf</li>
  <li data-at="bar" data-st="3" data-dpt="b">tazxsw</li>
  <li data-at="bar" data-st="1" data-dpt="b">zxcvb</li>
  <li data-at="foo" data-st="1" data-dpt="b">poiuy</li>
  <li data-at="boo" data-st="2" data-dpt="d">lkjhg</li>
  <li data-at="boo" data-st="3" data-dpt="d">lkjhg</li>
</ul>
```

The above is performing 'AND' logic on each chosen option. To change this to an 'OR', use the below:

```
$('.stat').on('click', function() {
  var $stats = $('.stat:checked');
  var $items = $('.list li');

  if ($stats.length == 0) {
    $items.show();
    return;
  }

  $items.hide();
  $stats.each(function() {
    var $stat = $(this);
    $items.filter(function() {
      return $(this).data($stat.data('type')) == $stat.data('id');
    }).show();
  })
});
```

Comment: thanks but when i select all check box its showing nothing

Comment: That's because it's doing a logical 'AND' on each option. I updated the answer to include an 'OR' alternative for you

Comment: I need to show all options when all check box selected , how to change it

Comment: actually it works but this is not what i expect .. if i choose any 2 check box from same filter it should work as logical OR and if iam selecting from one checkbox from one filter and other check box from another filter it should work as 'AND'