# Check if a comma separated data attribute contains a list of values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Originally from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867170/multiple-filter-using-jquery-with-data-attribute) - I have modified this to suit.

However, my data attributes (i.e. data-mktg-brand) are comma separated.

> $(this).data($mktgtype.data('type')) != $mktgtype.data('id');

I understand the above looks for what is not equal, but this means anything comma separated never works when one of the values is selected (i.e. selecting 'Brand 1' any articles with data-mktg-brand="Brand 1, Brand 2" are not returned)

What operator would let me check if a data attribute **contained** the checkbox data-id?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('.mktg-filter').on('click', function() {
  var $mktgtypes = $('.mktg-filter:checked');
  var $items = $('#mtkg-resource-list article');

  $items.show();
  if ($mktgtypes.length == 0)
    return;

  $mktgtypes.each(function() {
    var $mktgtype = $(this);
    $items.filter(function() {
      return $(this).data($mktgtype.data('type')) != $mktgtype.data('id');
    }).hide();
  })
});
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="brand-attribute" class="row">
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Brand 1" data-type="mktg-brand" class="mktg-filter mktg-brand" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Brand 1</label></div>
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Brand 2" data-type="mktg-brand" class="mktg-filter mktg-brand" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Brand 2</label></div>
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Brand 3" data-type="mktg-brand" class="mktg-filter mktg-brand" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Brand 3</label></div>
</div>
<div id="resource-attribute" class="row">
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Type 1" data-type="mktg-type" class="mktg-filter mktg-type" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Type 1</label></div>
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Type 2" data-type="mktg-type" class="mktg-filter mktg-type" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Type 2</label></div>
</div>
<div id="mktg-resource-list" class="row">
   <article class="col-12 col-md-6" data-mktg-brand="Brand 1, Brand 2" data-mktg-type="Type 1, Type 2" style="">
      <h3>Resource 1 Title</h3>
   </article>
   <article class="col-12 col-md-6" data-mktg-brand="Brand 3" data-mktg-type="Type 1" style="">
      <h3>Resource 2 Title</h3>
   </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of changes done to achieve what is required. There is a spelling mistake in below mentioned code (div id).

```
var $items = $('#mtkg-resource-list article');
```

Use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to check whether string is part of comma separated values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('.mktg-filter').on('click', function() {
  var $mktgtypes = $('.mktg-filter:checked');
  var $items = $('#mktg-resource-list article');
  $items.show();
  if ($mktgtypes.length == 0)
    return;

  $mktgtypes.each(function() {
    var $mktgtype = $(this);
    $items.hide().filter(function() {
      return $(this).data($mktgtype.data('type')).split(",").map(item => item.trim()).indexOf($mktgtype.data('id')) !== -1 || 
      $(this).data("mktg-brand").split(",").map(item => item.trim()).indexOf($mktgtype.text()) !== -1;
    }).show();
  })
});
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="brand-attribute" class="row">
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Brand 1" data-type="mktg-brand" class="mktg-filter mktg-brand" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Brand 1</label></div>
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Brand 2" data-type="mktg-brand" class="mktg-filter mktg-brand" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Brand 2</label></div>
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Brand 3" data-type="mktg-brand" class="mktg-filter mktg-brand" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Brand 3</label></div>
</div>
<div id="resource-attribute" class="row">
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Type 1" data-type="mktg-type" class="mktg-filter mktg-type" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Type 1</label></div>
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Type 2" data-type="mktg-type" class="mktg-filter mktg-type" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Type 2</label></div>
</div>
<div id="mktg-resource-list" class="row">
   <article class="col-12 col-md-6" data-mktg-brand="Brand 1, Brand 2" data-mktg-type="Type 1, Type 2" style="">
      <h3>Resource 1 Title</h3>
   </article>
   <article class="col-12 col-md-6" data-mktg-brand="Brand 3" data-mktg-type="Type 1" style="">
      <h3>Resource 2 Title</h3>
   </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much - corrected my typo and this worked! Much appreciated! :)

Comment: 1、`indexOf` would be wrong if there're such values as `Brand 11` and `Brand 1`
2、select `Brand 1` and `Type 1`, both articles should be shown, but it's wrong

Comment: @Taurz Updated code to split string and compare.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('.mktg-filter').on('click', function() {
    var $mktgtypes = $('.mktg-filter:checked');
    //you made a typo here, 'mktg-...' not 'mtkg-...'
    var $items = $('#mktg-resource-list article');

    $items.show();
    if ($mktgtypes.length == 0)
      return;
    const checked = $mktgtypes.map(function() {
      var $mktgtype = $(this);
      return {type:$mktgtype.data('type'), value:$mktgtype.data('id')};
     }).get();
    $items.filter(function(){
       const $item = $(this);
       return !checked.some(info => $item.data(info.type).split(",").map(value => value.trim()).includes(info.value));
     }).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="brand-attribute" class="row">
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Brand 1" data-type="mktg-brand" class="mktg-filter mktg-brand" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Brand 1</label></div>
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Brand 2" data-type="mktg-brand" class="mktg-filter mktg-brand" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Brand 2</label></div>
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Brand 3" data-type="mktg-brand" class="mktg-filter mktg-brand" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Brand 3</label></div>
</div>
<div id="resource-attribute" class="row">
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Type 1" data-type="mktg-type" class="mktg-filter mktg-type" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Type 1</label></div>
   <div class="col-12 mb-1"><input data-id="Type 2" data-type="mktg-type" class="mktg-filter mktg-type" type="checkbox"><label class="mktg-filter-label">Type 2</label></div>
</div>
<div id="mktg-resource-list" class="row">
   <article class="col-12 col-md-6" data-mktg-brand="Brand 1, Brand 2" data-mktg-type="Type 1, Type 2" style="">
      <h3>Resource 1 Title</h3>
   </article>
   <article class="col-12 col-md-6" data-mktg-brand="Brand 3" data-mktg-type="Type 1" style="">
      <h3>Resource 2 Title</h3>
   </article>
</div>
```